# Linux - Shell script - read ttyUSB0 file descriptor while no key pressed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am connecting to an uart via usb , I send a file to it

how do I read the file descriptor in a while loop ...

while no key has been pressed ?

- I tried **read -t 0.25 -N 1 input** but even if I press q, the loop does not break
- how do I check for the escape key instead

```
#!/bin/bash

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
exec 9<>/dev/ttyUSB0
cat somefile.txt >&9

while true; do
  read answer <&9 ; echo "$answer"

  read -t 0.25 -N 1 input
  if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]]; then
      break
  fi
done

exec 9>&-
```

cannot find the answer anywhere

thanks

Comment: Do you expect `q` to exit the loop while `read answer <&9 ` is waiting for a line from the device?

Comment: indeed...maybe I should use -t too